# Cause tests to fail when error is thrown after test has completed

Tags: jasmine, jestjs

I'm trying to find a way to make sure none of my jest tests are throwing errors from an async function.

For instance this test will succeed but will throw an error after the test has completed:

```
it ('should throw error', ()=> {
   setTimeout(()=> {
      throw 'this should fail tests!!'
   }, 100)

   expect(1).toEqual(1)
})
```

I want a way for that thrown error to cause the the entire test suite to fail, even though that single test has already concluded.

I know that error will show up in the console but that can easily be missed when you have hundreds of tests running.  Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: sample is too synthetic. if function does not provide any side effect just throws error OR if all side effects you expect happened successfully there is no value in knowledge if there was an error throw afterwards. From the other side, knowing what side effect should be - you can validate against them. And if they are not arriving it does not matter if error was thrown or not.

Comment: @skyboyer My sample is super simple to get my point across but in more complex cases there may be an issue in the async call (type errors, reference errors, etc) and it's possible that no test was actually written for that call. In a project that doesn't enforce coverage, this can easily happen.  Also I personally love a clean test console output and would love to enforce that if possible :)

Comment: I see what you mean. Probably, I was not specific enough. Real async code has side-effects. You can and should validate against it. There is no value in validating run-time errors themselves until they _are expected by other code_. But in such a case there would be `Promise` returned with rejection rather just an error message in console.